# Utility of a load resistance for measuring another resistance

Tags: resistors, multimeter, load

In [this paper](https://doi.org/10.1038/srep41716) they need to measure the value of an unknown resistance RS, whose value is the output signal of a sensor. However, instead of measuring this resistance directly with a multimeter, they place a *load resistance* RL in series with it, connect the circuit to a DC current, and read the voltage VL across that resistance:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fdEMgA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Then, the value of RS can be found using the following expression, where Vc is the applied voltage and Vout the voltage VL across the load resistance:

[image]

I wonder what the utility of introducing this *load resistance* is. Why don't they measure directly the resistance Rs connecting it to an ohmmeter? Would it improve the precision of the value of RS obtained?

Comment: Vc and Rs are in a `black box` ... the internal node is not accessible

Comment: What is an "Ohmnimeter"? What does it do? How does it work?

Comment: @brhans it was a typo, I changed it with "ohmmeter", thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand why they did it either: on the one hand they have a high quality meter, and on the other they are measuring very high resistances.

According to your cited paper:

> **To allow a more sensitive detection** of gas in our set-up, we used a load resistance RL. Input voltage, VC, of 1 V was applied from DC power supply ... RL is connected in series with the sensor and its value is 491.3kΩ. The output voltage, Vout, was measured across RL. ... output signal (voltage) was recorded using Fluke Digital Multimeters 287/289"

The resistances are pretty high for one of their sensors (400 GΩ per first graph of figure 6.) which appears to be off the range of the Fluke meters.  In the potential divider arrangement (approx 500 K / 400 G) they should see about a microvolt, also off the range.  (And surely susceptible to noise?).  It's possible they were not measuring the ZnO sensor with the circuit they show.

For the second sensor Na:ZnO they have about 3 MΩ easily measured by the meter.  It's not clear what advantage this potential divider has over using the meter directly.

In passing the meter has a slightly better accuracy for voltage (0.025%) than resistance (0.05%) according to their datasheets (Fluke [287](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/705042.pdf), [289](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1640372.pdf)).

Comment: One way to get the 400GΩ measurement to work would be to omit the external R_L and just use the input impedance of the meter - not what they report but it could work. The other benefit to this setup is that you have a known voltage across your DUT - multimeters use a variety of excitation voltages to measure resistance directly.

Comment: Yes I see your point about the voltage used --  If their sensors are even conceivably sensitive to that I can see it's a benefit to have a published voltage.

Comment: Also, there's another "mystery" piece of equipment in Fig. 7, which might be doing some part of the measurement - above the power supply and to the right of the Fluke 287

Comment: Yes, I wonder what it is.

Comment: From a google image search, looks like it could be a Fluke 8000A, which is just a 3.5 digit DMM, nothing special. So I'm still skeptical that they accurately measured 400GΩ exactly the way they wrote it up.

Answer (score 1):

The load resistance forms a voltage divider with the sensor. Standard equations apply.

You are essentially creating an ohm meter. So there is no advantage, except perhaps that you can tune the component values to match the range of RS.

A wheatstone bridge is another configuration that can be used to measure resistance.

Comment: I was asking the question with regard to the advantages of using the circuit in the diagram over measuring directly the RL resistance with an Ohmnimeter...

Comment: Sorry missed that. Updated my answer. You are essentially creating an ohm meter, so there is no advantage if your system can already read ohms directly.

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to measure resistance.

One way is to source a known current the unknown resistance and then the voltage across it is measured, knowing the current and voltage gives you the resistance, \$R=\frac{V}{I}\$

Another way is to source a known voltage across the resistance and then the current is measured, again knowing the current and voltage gives you the resistance, \$R=\frac{V}{I}\$

The circuit you have is basically using the second method, with \$V_c\$ being the known voltage and the \$500k\Omega\$ resistor and voltmeter being used to measure the current. Doing it this way allows you to make the current measurement very sensitive by reading the voltage over a relatively large resistance, this will allow it to measure much higher resistances then a standard multimeter, which usually use the constant current method.

There are other ways of measuring resistance, such as comparing to a known resistance in a bridge circuit.

Comment: In the cited paper they are apparently reading 400 GOhm for which the 500 KOhm is actually pretty small.  Wouldn't we expect a wheatstone bridge for measuring Rs?  And for their second 3 MOhm reading, why use the potential divider rather than the high quality meter directly?